# Where do stored procedures and other objects reside on disk?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**The question:** Is there somewhere on the disk where I might find human-readable files for each procedure / trigger on a Database instance?

I've looked through `Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\` on my disk but it's mostly just .dll / .rll files.

The reason I ask is because my company has decided to increase a certain `VARCHAR(10)` field to `VARCHAR(50)` and this field makes an appearance in 350+ stored procedures / triggers. And it's my job to figure out which of these scripts need to be modified to account for this field length increase. It'd be great if I could just write a script to parse out these files and identify ones that match various different regular expressions.

Comment: In the database itself. Use `syscomments` or `sys.sql_modules`.

Answer (score 3):

as shawnt00 mentioned stored procedures [SP], functions, table definitions, etc. are stored in the database files themselves not with the file system.  But you can use system views to query against the SP or Function text to attempt to find the column/variable you are looking for.

The one exception is any object that is encrypted as the text definition of the object will not be in clear text but rather it will be encrypted so it will not be returned from a query like this.

```
SELECT
    SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) as SchemaName
    ,o.name AS ObjectName
    ,o.type
    ,o.type_desc
    ,m.definition as ObjectText
FROM
    sys.sql_modules m
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o
    ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE
    m.definition LIKE '%VARCHAR(10)%'
```

Comment: Yea I used `sys.sql_modules` to identify the 350+ scripts of interest, however I was not aware of what exactly the  `definition` column contains. Looking into it further, I understand now.  I can execute that query from my code and then iterate over the results and parse out the procedures of interest that way. Thanks.

Comment: yep good luck, 350+ doesn't sound like much fun but been there done that :)